# What is the difference between signed vim and unsigned vim?

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows

On the vim.org download page, there's an option to download a "signed" version of vim for windows (https://www.vim.org/download.php). What is the difference between using one of the "signed" files to download vim versus the the unsigned version you get when you use the windows installer?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: I too am intrigued by this. As a generality, signed releases allow you to verify the code using a project/author's public key...What I want to know is why they're presenting both signed and unsigned versions?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is simply the case that not all releases were/are signed. As such, if you are limited to only signed versions, you might not be getting the most recent build.

Somewhat at odds with that is the fact that they list both signed and unsigned downloads  under the same version number on github:
https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/releases

From that, I can only conclude that they're different binary builds (i.e. different features) by different authors/teams, but they are built from the same version of the source code...

See a bit of discussion here:
https://groups.google.com/g/vim_dev/c/dn2vwGlcEJk
https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/l4pg1j/is_gvim_portable_by_itself_windows_10/gksph0u?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3